# Check the proof of: $(A')^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}\right)'$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Prove: $(A')^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}\right)'$.

$$\begin{align*}\left(A^{-1}\right)'=\left(\frac{1}{\det (A)}A^*\right)'=\frac{1}{\det (A)}\left(A^*\right)'=\frac{1}{\det (A)}(A')^*=(A')^{-1}\end{align*}$$

Is it right?（This is the question...）Duplicate?

---

$A'$ is the transpose of A.

$A^*$ is the adjugate matrix

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the difference between $A'$ and $A^*$?

Comment: I think $A'$ is the transpose and $A^*$ is the matrix of cofactors.

Comment: Let us give the OP the opportunity to explain his notation...

Comment: It is right, but incomplete. You need to show that $(A^*)' = (A')^*$, since you're using it and it's not obviously true.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure $\left(A^*\right)'=\left(A'\right)^*$ is easier to prove than your statement.

You probably know $\left(AB\right)'=B'A'$. From that $I=I'=\left(AA^{-1}\right)'=\left(A^{-1}\right)'A'$ so $\left(A'\right)^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}\right)'$.

Answer (score 2):

More simply:

$(A')\left(A^{-1}\right)'= \left(A^{-1} A\right)'=I'=I$, hence $A'$ is ionverse to $\left(A^{-1}\right)'$.

Comment: I would have written this, too.  But, technically it does not answer the question ("Is it right?")

Comment: @ GEdgar 9 : Yes, you are right.